# Presentation of a longitudinal dataframe, counting by year

Tags: dataframe, ggplot2, longitudinal

I'm hoping one of you can help me, with this probably easy question. The thing is, I have a longitudinal dataframe, that looks something like this:

```
id <- c('1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3')
year <- c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014)
ue <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
mydata <- data.frame(id, year, ue)
```

The `ue` variable indicates whether a respondent received an unemployment benefit in a given year.

1. First I want to create a simple table which tells me how many are receiving a ue-benefit in the specific year. Something like this:

```
  year ue
1 2012  3
2 2013  2
3 2014  1
```

2. I want to present the following table in an appropriate plot - ex a histogram.

I hope some of you can help you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyverse` to get a summary of the data.

library(tidyverse)

```
output <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(ue = sum(ue))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year    ue
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2012     3
2  2013     2
3  2014     1
```

If you want the output of that table, then you probably want to use `geom_col` from `ggplot2`.

```
ggplot(output) +
  geom_col(aes(x = year, y = ue)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: That works. However, it seems like I have a lot of NA's in my data, so my table only gets me NA for every year. Any suggestions? I figure it out myself, just adding na.rm = TRUE